# Two questions regarding quotients and fraction fields of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The first one is: consider the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = ([x^2],[x^3]) $ of the local ring $A=k[x^2,x^3]/(x^4)$. Is it true that $\mathfrak{m}^2=0$? In my opinion, $\mathfrak{m}^2$ is generated by $[x^4],[x^5]$ and $[x^6]$. I can see why the first and the last are $0$, by why should $[x^5]=0$ in $A$, since $[x]$ is not in $A$?

Second question: consider the ring $A=k[x,y,z,w]/(xz-y^2,yz-xw,z^2-yw)$. I am told that its fraction field is $K=k\left(\frac{[y]}{[z]}\right)$, but I cannot see how one could recover for instance $[x] \in A \subseteq K$ as a $k-$multiple of some (possibly negative) power of $\frac{[y]}{[z]}$.

Note: throughout, the square brackets denote equivalence classes in the quotient ring (except in the obvious cases when they just adjoin variables to $k$).

Comment: You have (I think correctly) assumed that “$(x^4)$” means $Bx^4$, where $B=k[x^2,x^3]$. I confess that I first interpreted $(x^4)$ to be the ideal $x^4k[x]$, which would make $[x^5]=0$, but I believe that I was wrong in this. I agree that $[x^5]\ne0$ in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $k[x^2,x^3]/(x^4)\cong k[y,z]/(y^3-x^2,y^2)$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1802523/11653). So $\mathfrak m=(z,y)$ represents the origin and $\mathfrak m^2=(zy)$ is not the zero ideal, because $zy$ does not vanish on the entire cusp.

Furthermore, $R:=k[x,y,z,w]/(xz-y^2,yz-xw,z^2-yw)$ is a naturally graded ring and the elements of $k([y]/[z])$ all have degree zero. Hence, it cannot be the quotient field of $R$. It is, however, the degree $0$ component of $K$. Note that
$$
K_0 = k\left( \tfrac{[x]}{[z]}, \tfrac{[y]}{[z]}, \tfrac{[w]}{[z]} \right)
$$
and we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{[w]}{[z]}&=\frac{[xw]}{[xz]}=\frac{[yz]}{[y^2]}=\frac{[z]}{[y]}=\left(\frac{[y]}{[z]}\right)^{-1}, \\
\frac{[x]}{[z]}&=\frac{[xw]}{[zw]}=\frac{[yz]}{[zw]}=\frac{[y]}{[w]}
=\frac{[y^2]}{[yw]}=\frac{[y^2]}{[z^2]}=\left(\frac{[y]}{[z]}\right)^2,
\end{align*}
which shows that $K_0=k\left( \tfrac{[y]}{[z]} \right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was puzzled because the examples are to be found in quite famous books (Atiyah-Macdonald's "Commutative Algebra" and Liu's "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves") ad it seemed strange that they could both be wrong, so I thought that I must be missing something. But, apparently, even the best books contain mistakes :)

Comment: Ok, actually in Liu I just interpreted the assertion in the wrong way...